# How to solve the UnsatisfiedDependencyException after a bunch of changes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I'm new to Spring world and need some thoughts for this problem.
After I updated a bunch of files, the Spring web service could not bootrun successfully.

`TestMainApplication` is my main bootstrap file.

I belelive the root cause is from `chartServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6;`
However, I haven't updated anything from `secondaryChannelServiceImpl`.

Any idea or direction to look into this kind of issue?

Constructor duplicates problem or?

```
    at com.iicloud.goodOrg.TestMain.service.TestMainApplication.main(TestMainApplication.java:69)

    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 

    Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency 
    expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'TestMainApplication': 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'chartService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'chartServiceImpl' defined in file [.../charts/service/impl/chartServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'secondaryChannelServiceImpl'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UnsatisfiedDependencyException might occur due to multiple reasons.

- If we don't create a bean for a particular class or if we miss the @Component annotation for the class. Spring will not manage those classes and thus spring container will not create an object to autowire.
- Autowiring classes that are not part of the packages included for the component scan. Spring will search for components only within the packages that are included in the package scan.
- If there are non-unique dependency resolutions. If there are two are more implementations for an interface, Spring will not know which one to autowire. This can be avoided by mentioning the right implementation using @Qualifier annotation along with @Autowired.

Comment: Will try these directions you meantioned. Thank you so much!